# ¿Se puede agregar más de un KeyFieldName en un GridView de DevExpress?

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress

Tengo un proyecto web en el que tengo una grilla donde muestro la secuencia de un recorrido que tiene una empresa.
En esta grilla tengo `idEmpresa`, `idSucursal`, `idRonda`, `orden` y `tiempoOptimo`. Las claves de esta tabla son `idEmpresa`, `idSucursal`, `idRonda`, `orden`, pero en el `GridView` sólo puedo poner uno de estos 4 campos, lo cual me resulta imposible porque cuando quiero editar alguno de estos, me abre el panel para editar todos los registros similares.

Por ejemplo: Si pongo `keyfieldname="orden"` me va a abrir el panel con todos los registros con el mismo orden.
No se si llego a explicarme.

De esta manera tengo configurado el `GridView`:

```
<dx:aspxgridview id="gv_Rondas" runat="server" autogeneratecolumns="False" keyfieldname="orden" width="95%" theme="MetropolisBlue"
            onrowupdating="gv_Rondas_RowUpdating"
            onrowdeleting="gv_Rondas_RowDeleting"
            oncelleditorinitialize="gv_Rondas_CellEditorInitialize"
            OnDataBinding="gv_Rondas_DataBinding" >

...

</dx:aspxgridview>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si, cuesta de encontrar documentación de esto, a mi me ocurrió, pero hay alguna pregunta en su [sitio web](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T305413/aspxgridview-how-to-set-keyfieldname-for-multiple-column) que lo contestan.

Debes poner los campos separados por un punto y coma (;)

```
keyfieldname="idEmpresa;idSucursal;idRonda;orden"
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! yo justamente lo estaba separando por coma y no me funcionaba. Sabía que debía ser algo sencillo jaja